# Fatal error: Call to a member function raw() on a non-object in

Tags: entities

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function raw() on a non-object in one of my custom modules.

Following is my function:

```
function _gocoop_services_get_app_instance($wrapper)
{
  $instance_id = $wrapper->field_seller->field_application_instance->raw();
  if (!$instance_id)
  {
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'application_instance')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'application_instance')
        ->fieldCondition('field_internal', 'value', 1);
    $result = $query->execute();
    if ($result['application_instance'])
    {
      $instance_id = reset(array_keys($result['application_instance']));
    }
  }
  return $instance_id;
}
```

Have used the above function at couple of places like shown below:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $entity);
$instance_id = _gocoop_services_get_app_instance($wrapper);
```

Can anyone help me whats wrong as this has occurred all of a sudden.

Comment: `wrapper->field_seller->field_application_instance` isn't an object, hence the error message. Couldn't say why without proper details of the problem and the data you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this instead, checking if the field value is set first and catching the exception.

```
function _gocoop_services_get_app_instance($wrapper) {
  $instance_id = FALSE;
  try {
    // Check if wrapper field set first
    if (isset($wrapper->field_seller) && isset($wrapper->field_seller->field_application_instance)) {
      $instance_id = $wrapper->field_seller->field_application_instance->raw();
    }
    if (!$instance_id) {
      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'application_instance')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', 'application_instance')
          ->fieldCondition('field_internal', 'value', 1);
      $result = $query->execute();
      if ($result['application_instance']) {
        $instance_id = reset(array_keys($result['application_instance']));
      }
    }
  } catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
    watchdog_exception('gocoop', $e);
  }
  return $instance_id;
}
```

You might also want to use a static cache for `$instance_id`, but that would need to vary based on your `$wrapper` id value.

Comment: Thanks David. This atleast helped me in getting out of the error.